# A seriously confuse recipe - or is it?

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

> - Mix one teaspoon of the first ingredient with one of the second ingredient in a bowl.
> - In another bowl, repeat the operation, adding one more teaspoon of the second ingredient. Repeat again until you run out of bowls.
> - Pour the mixtures in separate plates and arrange by order of weight.
> - Fill again two bowls in the same manner (with any quantity of the second ingredient). Pour one bowl upside-down over the other and bake until only the excess part remains.
> - Repeat the last operation for all ingredient proportions, discarding the result when you previously obtained the same weight.
> - Pour once more the mixtures in plates, arranged by order of weight.
>
> Serve warm

**What is this recipe for?

What are the two ingredients involved?**

Hints:

> Pouring one bowl into the other is not a division

---

> The number of bowls is countably infinite

Comment: To be clear, you want plates containing ingredient A and ingredient B in this fashion (for n plates): 1A + 1B, 1A + 2B, 1A + 3B, ... , 1A + nB, each topped with an arbitrary amount of B mixed with B baked until only a constituent of B remains (edit: such that if we call baked B ingredient C, by weight C = 1A + nB for whichever n)?

Comment: Correct about 1A+nB, but C does not really weighs the same. Some sort of chemical reaction occurs, changing the weight when baking.

Comment: Clearly it's a recipe for disaster

Comment: It reminds me of [CHEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language#Chef)

Comment: This is totally the CHEF programming language.

Comment: "Repeat again until you run out of bowls" and then "Fill again two bowls"... Where do we get these 2 bowls from, if we already ran out of them?!

Comment: @hyst, they were poured into plates

Comment: My guess is water.  The two ingredients are Hydrogen and Oxygen.  The math involved could be getting the proportions right.  Baking (heat) is required to cause the hydrogen to burn and bond with the oxygen. Serve warm so that it is in liquid (consumable) form instead of ice (cold) or steam (hot).

Comment: I just can't figure out the second set of steps.  You fill two bowls with the second ingredient, combine them (one upside down; this must be important somehow) and then bake, leaving only the remainder.  If "baking" is division and the excess is the remainder of this division, then you probably get the sequence $1, 2, 3, \dots$.

Comment: @Trenin, First, the second set of steps does not use only the second ingredient. It has the first one just the same way (although that's not important). The bowls are done the same way, but them they are combined. Second, the hint says "baking" is **not** division.

Comment: @fffred Reading the clue literally says "Fill again two bowls, with any quantity of the second ingredient."  First ingredient is not mentioned.  Is this intended?  Because I read it as you have two bowls, both with any quantity of the second ingredient.  If you are supposed to have one bowl with the first ingredient and one with the second then I think it might need to be made more clear.

Comment: @fffred I get baking is not division.  If my guess is right ($H_2O$), then baking is converting 2 parts hydrogen and 1 part oxygen to water leaving only Hydrogen (or Oxygen, depending on which there is more of).  But from the clue, I can't see how much (if any) of the first ingredient one is supposed to use.  As it is written, the first ingredient is not used at all.

Comment: @Trenin, this is a dead end :(

Answer (score 2):

I think the recipe is for

> the universe

and the ingredients are

> antimatter and matter

Mix one teaspoon of the first ingredient with one of the second ingredient in a bowl.

> near-equal amounts of AM and M were created during the big bang -- mixing M & AM leads them to annihilate each other into pure energy

In another bowl, repeat the operation, adding one more teaspoon of the second ingredient. Repeat again until you run out of bowls.

> At the end of the process, we have matter (and very little AM) left over

Pour the mixtures in separate plates and arrange by order of weight.

> The universe is made of (mostly? always? spinning) galaxies, in which the heavy parts (e.g. black holes) tend towards the middle

Fill again two bowls, with any quantity of the second ingredient. Pour one bowl upside-down over the other and bake until only the excess part remains.

> This language confuses me a little, but this sounds like star-formation (from matter). OR (based on the next step) it is baking the planets.

Repeat the last operation for all ingredient proportions, discarding the result when you previously obtained the same weight.
Pour once more the mixtures in plates, arranged by order of weight.

> planetary systems (like our little one orbiting Sol)?

Serve warm

> Our universe is a awash with the background "heat" from the big bang!

Comment: Ha ha I didn't think about this! But a real nice coincidence!

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

- Fill again two bowls, with any quantity of the second ingredient. Pour one bowl upside-down over the other and bake until only the excess part remains.

> Sounds like getting any two numbers and write them as fraction (*one bowl over the other*), then simplifying it (*bake until only the excess part remains*)

- Repeat the last operation for all ingredient proportions, discarding the result when you previously obtained the same weight.

> Discard fractions already present.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the harmonic series-- 1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,...

Answer (score 0):

So, if this is just a series:

Divesting the riddle of the cooking wordage you end up with (B/B)/(A + kB), or 1/(A + kB) for k = 1 .. n. It's convergent, but to what I don't know (since I have no way of determining A and B from the information given).